# Plotly: How to move the color bar on a treemap?

Tags: python, plotly, treemap

How do I move the color bar from the right-hand side to the bottom or top so that it appears horizontally?

Reproducible example below:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
df["world"] = "world" # in order to have a single root node
fig = px.treemap(df, path=['world', 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
fig.show()
```

[image: treemap]

Attempt:

```
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=1.02,
    xanchor="right",
    x=1
))
```

Not sure why the above doesn't work?

Comment: Is it a legend? I think you mean the color bar.

Comment: yes the color bar! Sorry, i'll edit the title and description to reflect that :)

Comment: At the moment, it doesn't seem to be possible to make the color bar horizontal. There is a comment that it may be added in a future update. Please refer to [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1244).